# ASP.NET FormView: Including a Member Variable in an XPath Expression

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Is something like this possible?

```
<asp:FormView ID="myFormView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%# XPath("Root/Path/Item[@id=<%=this.m_myId%>]/HelloWorld")%></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

m_myId is a member variable on the page.  I can't seem to get it to work without a parsing error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have nested asp tags.  Try something like this:

```
<%# XPath("Root/Path/Item[@id= " + this.m_myId + "]/HelloWorld") %>
```